# Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:5:"error";s:16:"consent_required";}

Tags: php, laravel, docusign-sdk

Hello i've tried to implement docusign in my project and i have followed this exemple :
https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/send-document-laravel-jwt-grant-authentication
but i can' make it works, when i try to authenticate I've got this error "Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:5:"error";s:16:"consent_required";}"
i already granted the consent in docusign
[here is the image that's shows the consent in docusign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9FVf.png).

if someone can help me i will be grateful
or if you could provide me guidance through docusign using jwt without showing login form that will help me a lot.

i've also tried to follow this https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdks/php/auth/ but i can't figured it out.

thanks a lot.

**Update**

here is my controller  i call the function send on Submit  :
public function send(Request $request): object{

```
    /** 
     * 
     * Step 1
     * Instantiate the eSign API client and set the OAuth path used by the JWT request
     * 
     * Generate a new JWT access token
     * 
     */ 
    $apiClient = new ApiClient();
   
    $apiClient->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath(config('app.auth_server')); 
    try{
        $accessToken = $this->getToken($apiClient);
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return back()->withError($th->getMessage())->withInput();
    }
    /**
     * 
     * Step 2
     * Get user's info i.e. accounts array and base path
     * 
     * Update the base path. The result in demo will be https://demo.docusign.net/restapi
     * User default account is always first in the array
     * 
     */
    
    $userInfo = $apiClient->getUserInfo($accessToken);
    $accountInfo = $userInfo[0]->getAccounts();
    $apiClient->getConfig()->setHost($accountInfo[0]->getBaseUri() . config('app.sufix'));        
    /**
     * 
     * Step 3
     * Build the envelope object
     * 
     * Make an API call to create the envelope and display the response in the view
     * 
     */
    $envelopeDefenition = $this->buildEnvelope($request);           
    try {            
        $envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
        $result = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountInfo[0]->getAccountId(), $envelopeDefenition);
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return back()->withError($th->getMessage())->withInput();
    }      
    return view('contract.response')->with('result', $result);

}

private function getToken(ApiClient $apiClient) : string{
    try {
        $privateKey = file_get_contents(storage_path(config('app.keypath')),true);
        $response = $apiClient->requestJWTUserToken(
            $ikey = config('app.client'),
            $userId = config('app.user_id'),
            $key = $privateKey,
            $scope = config('app.JWT_SCOPE')
     
        );        
        $token = $response[0];
        dd($token);
        $accessToken = $token->getAccessToken();
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        throw $th;
    }    
    return $accessToken;        
}
```

Comment: So what you need is a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example show the controller, show the part where you're making the call to docusign. When you have an error, copy/paste the part of the error log **with stacktrace** and update your original question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i've added some code that i'm working on it , if you could please check it and tell me if that's ok. thank you in advance

Comment: Open the laravel.log and ocopy/paste the error **with its entire stacktrace** to your original question

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have checked my laravel.log but it's empty : there is no information  regarding the error displayed in my view.